# Delete line in string python

Tags: python, string, line, delete-row

What is the most efficient way to delete a line from a string in python? I have tried

```
content = "first line \nsecond line\nthird line\netc.".splitlines()

i = 0
for line in iter(content):
  if len(line) < 5:
    content[i] = "" 
  i += 1

content = '\n'.join(content)
```

where my delete condition is just that the length of the line is smaller than 5 characters. Is there a more elegant/efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more concise one using a list comprehension:

```
'\n'.join([i if len(i) > 5 else '' for i in content.split('\n')])
#'first line \nsecond line\nthird line\n'
```

---

Now working from your approach... note that content is already an iterator, so there's no need for `iter(content)`.

What else can be improved? Well instead of using a counter, python has a built-in function for that, [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html). Using it your code could look like:

```
content = "first line \nsecond line\nthird line\netc."
content = content.splitlines()

for i, line in enumerate(content):
      if len(line) < 5:
            content[i] = "" 

separator = '\n'
content = separator.join(content)
```

Comment: No, but `join` is expecting a list, so it is actually somewhat faster when fed a list rather than a gen-comp @hansolo since it will construct a list anyway

Comment: Also please comment to double check before actually modifying a post

Comment: you don't need the `else ''` part. `[i for i in content.split('\n') if len(i) > 5]` would do

Comment: @buran, you do if you want an empty line as OP had in their question.

Comment: @Holloway, yes, I didn't notice that in OP code. So if they really need empty line, then my previous comment is incorrect

Comment: @yatu the line of code you wrote does not delete any line for some reason.

Comment: Sure it does @Gepeto97 , its working for me with for instance `content = "first line \nse\nthird line\netc."`

Comment: Ok then you have to attribute it to the variable i.e. `content='\n'.join([i if len(i) > 5 else '' for i in content.split('\n')])` I got it now, thanks.

Comment: YW, don't forget to upvote and accept if it helped :) @Gepeto97

Comment: @yatu Yep, `list` is faster than `gen-exporession` for `join`. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Python Regex:

```py
import re
content = "first line \nsecond line\nthird line\netc."
print(re.sub(r'^.{1,5}$', '', content, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Resulting:

```
'first line \nsecond line\nthird line\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

yatu's answer is nice and pythonic, but we can go further!

```
content = "first line \nsecond line\nthird line\netc."

content = '\n'.join(
    i if len(i) > 5 else ''
        for i in content.splitlines()
)

content
#'first line \nsecond line\nthird line'
```

str.join takes any iterable, so here use a generator expression for more pythonicness!